# Issues compiling freenect via cmake

Tags: cmake, openkinect

I'm trying to compile [freenect](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect) and this is my first time using `cmake` a opposed to `make`. I had some erlier issues due to dependencies and I was able to resolve via google searches but now I'm stuck again. How do I resolve this? Terminal output below:

```
~/libfreenect-master $ sudo cmake -L
-- Operating system is Linux
-- Got System Processor armv6l
-- libfreenect will be installed to /usr/local
-- Headers will be installed to /usr/local/include/libfreenect
-- Libraries will be installed to /usr/local/lib
-- Found libusb-1.0:
--  - Includes: /usr/include/libusb-1.0
--  - Libraries: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-1.0.so
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
GLUT_Xmu_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)
    linked by target "freenect-chunkview" in directory /home/pi/libfreenect-master/examples
    linked by target "freenect-glpclview" in directory /home/pi/libfreenect-master/examples
    linked by target "freenect-glview" in directory /home/pi/libfreenect-master/examples
    linked by target "freenect-hiview" in directory /home/pi/libfreenect-master/examples
    linked by target "freenect-micview" in directory /home/pi/libfreenect-master/examples
    linked by target "freenect-regview" in directory /home/pi/libfreenect-master/examples
    linked by target "freenect-cpp_pcview" in directory /home/pi/libfreenect-master/wrappers/cpp
    linked by target "freenect-cppview" in directory /home/pi/libfreenect-master/wrappers/cpp

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
-- Cache values
BUILD_AS3_SERVER:BOOL=OFF
BUILD_CPACK_DEB:BOOL=OFF
BUILD_CPACK_RPM:BOOL=OFF
BUILD_CPACK_TGZ:BOOL=OFF
BUILD_CPP:BOOL=ON
BUILD_CV:BOOL=OFF
BUILD_C_SYNC:BOOL=ON
BUILD_EXAMPLES:BOOL=ON
BUILD_FAKENECT:BOOL=ON
BUILD_OPENNI2_DRIVER:BOOL=OFF
BUILD_PYTHON:BOOL=OFF
BUILD_REDIST_PACKAGE:BOOL=ON
CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=
CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr/local
LIBUSB_1_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/usr/include/libusb-1.0
LIBUSB_1_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-1.0.so
```

Comment: So? What about installing libxmu-dev and libxi-dev? BTW, CMake will generate you make files, thus it is not really opposed to, even if it might be true for this particular project.

Comment: @usr1234567's suggestion works for me.

Answer (score 0):

On mac osx I was able to use homebrew to install freenect which was super simple.

> `brew install libfreenect`
>
> And thats it, you are done! A copy of glview
>   demo should now be in your PATH so you can simply run:
>
> `freenect-glview`

http://openkinect.org/wiki/Getting_Started#Homebrew